# Admin tool for verifying Corda Node p2p communication

Tags: connection, corda, verification, communication-protocol

Are there any reasonably simple utilities that unix administrators could use to verify p2p communications between Corda nodes, Artemis brokers, which facilitate the node AMQP communication? For example, we need to ensure that the appropriate urls: ports are open inbound/outbound from Node to Notary cluster. It needs to be a command based tool, not a development exercise since the user would be an administrator.

For verification of Node to Doorman/Network Map since the communication is over HTTP the Node administrator may use command `curl http://<netmap url>:<netmap port>/network-map/my-ip`. What can be done to verify other protocol communications such as Node to Notary cluster?

---

Comment: Is the "p2p communications between Corda nodes" you're talking about actually referring to the communication that's part of the ActiveMQ Artemis clustering functionality or something specific to Corda? FWIW, the connections between Artemis cluster nodes don't use AMQP.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my q to focus on artemis. Corda uses Artemis for Node to Node communication using AMQP/TLS. Thanks!

Comment: Artemis doesn't use AMQP to communicate between nodes so these connections must be something specific to corda.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Corda tooling for doing this. However, you can use a standard tool like Telnet:

```
telnet localhost 10005
```